# In which place or APP of django should I store data?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Which is the secure and suitable place to store data in django? In already created APP like Users or in custom APP like Posts or something else?

Comment: What do you mean by *to store data* ?

Comment: I mean should I store username, password in admin already created app or in custom app? Which is the best and secure way?

Comment: Django has very good documentation and handling static files, databases and uploads are all described there. What additional information do you need?

Comment: I am beginner and just wanted to make registration, login and logout page but watch tutorials that how should I store username, password in admin already created app or in custom app? Which is the best and secure way?

Comment: If the user management of the admin app fits your need, then you shouldn't try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: It depends what app you want. If you want a simple app to store data like name, age, info etc. a PostgresDB will do the job.

If you want to save files like images etc AWS s3 will work fine for you or a dedicated server.

Comment: You are not getting me. Whenever I login into the admin panel in django it gives me the option of Groups and Users in AUTHENTICATION AND AUTHORIZATION. Should I store data in that Users or make another custom app by my own to store data?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extend the default Django User model you have several options. The choice depends on your needs. Briefly the options are:

- **Proxy model**: choose this way if you are satisfied with Django User model and don’t need to store extra information in database but need some extra methods.
- **Custom model** (aka User Profile) **with One-to-One link to default User model**: Django authentication process satisfies you but you need to store some extra data not supported by default User model.
- **Custom model inherited from `AbstractBaseUser`**: you want custom authentication flow and Django does not fit your needs.
- **Custom User Model from AbstractUser**: Django handles auth the way you need but you want to add extra attributes without creating a separate model.

For code examples and extra explanations please see the [article about extending Django User model by Vitor Freitas](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html) or its [russian translation by Tproger](https://tproger.ru/translations/extending-django-user-model/).